Bind a DataGridView element's IsVisible to a bool property
In my MAUI app I've added a DataGridView component from DevExpress and it shows rows from a list in the ViewModel. Each row contains an image.
<Image Source="icon.svg" />

I want the image to be visible only when a bool property (IsInLocalCache) in the related object from the list is true but whatever I try doesn't work. Eg. using binding or triggers or binding with explicitly defined Source.
<dxg:TemplateColumn Row="1" Column="3" ColumnSpan="1" Caption="Icon" IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False">
    <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="icon.svg" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference IsInLocalCache}}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
</dxg:TemplateColumn>

The related model:
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Guid DocId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DocStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    [SQLite.Ignore]
    public bool IsInLocalCache { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime? LastChangeDateTime { get; set; }
}

How can I make this work?

If we take this Property={Binding X, Source=Y}, the Property is the one you want to change, X - is the property you want to watch. Y is the object that has the property X. So, you are saying Bind IsVisible to IsVisible of the object IsInLocalCache.

Please post the relevant model code

@Jason, I added the model.

@H.A.H. so what should I use as the Y? The underlying instance has no given name.

IsVisible=“{Binding IsInLocalCache}”

@Val do what Jason said, and try to understand it.

@Jason, I've tried the simple binding  IsVisible=“{Binding IsInLocalCache}” and it didn't work hence why I'm posting the question.

try using an IValueConverter on the image source that will return null if the IsInLocalCache is false

I've tried the simple binding   IsVisible=“{Binding IsInLocalCache}” and it didn't work hence why I'm posting the question  You can try debugging to see the specific value of IsInLocalCache is true or false.

@JessieZhang-MSFT, I debugged and then I also hard-coded the values (first one, then the other) and they don't change anything. The visibility is not affected.

I did a test, but I could not reproduce this problem on my side. Could you please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example here so that we can test on my side?
